# Add "buy now " button in mini cart magento 2

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

Is there any way we can add a "buy now" button in the mini cart?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

https://magecomp.com/blog/magento-2-add-custom-button-in-minicart/

hope above link helps you!

I know 3rd party link not allowed but still for your reference.